# GDK function not found

Tags: c, gtk, gdk

I have a gtk program in which I am calling a gdk function. I am compiling the program using:

```
 gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 cairo glib-2.0` ...
```

and I have included

```
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
```

it gives me the error:

```
undefined reference to `gdk_device_ungrab'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you have oportunitz to use `pkgconfig` I'd recommend to do that, as it resolvs a lot of library and include grief for your (independant of  the specific solution to your problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are compiling and linking against gtk 2.x and `gdk_device_ungrab` is available only starting from gtk 3.0.

See:
http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.4/GdkDevice.html#gdk-device-ungrab

Answer (score -1):

You have to put your source or object files *before* the libraries in the command line, i.e. at the beginning, before the pkg-config part.

The linker adds objects and libraries in the order they are specified in the command line; if the gdk library is listed before your source file, the linker doesn't know your code needs the libray until it is too late.

Comment: I don't think that matters because it finds glib and gtk functions.